# Can't find the value in Array but when console.log, the value is there

Tags: angularjs

Please refer below console.log output for $scope.levels

[image]

And below is the code,

```
var lvl = _.find($scope.levels, function(l) {
                    return l.levelIndex === level + 1;
                });
```

value for level at this point is **2**

However, when I console.log for lvl, it is undefined.

[image]

Any idea why it's undefined? And how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

console what is happening as

```
console.log({ levelIndex :l.levelIndex , level });
```

this will show the values with name
check if it has value in it and if its returning true

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible the value you're checking for is a string, and your strict check is looking for a number. You can cast both sides as a number to test...

```
var lvl = _.find($scope.levels, function(l) {
   return +l.levelIndex === +level + 1;
});
```

or in vanilla JS

```
var lvl = $scope.levels.find(l => +l.levelIndex === +level + 1);
```

```js
var level = 2;
var $scope = {levels: [{levelIndex:2},{levelIndex:3}]};
var lvl = $scope.levels.find(l => +l.levelIndex === +level + 1);
console.log('lvl:',lvl);
```